# Native C extension not finding code used by Ruby core

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Based on browsing the Ruby API sources for `Array#length` and `Range#begin` I know that macros `RARRAY_LEN` and `RANGE_BEG` exist and are used to implement the corresponding methods:

### [Array#length](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/array#method-i-length)

```c
static VALUE
rb_ary_length(VALUE ary)
{
    long len = RARRAY_LEN(ary);
    return LONG2NUM(len);
}
```

### [Range#begin](https://rubyapi.org/3.1/o/range#method-i-begin)

```c
static VALUE
range_begin(VALUE range)
{
    return RANGE_BEG(range);
}
```

However, while the code below has no problems with `RARRAY_LEN` I have been unable to get `RANGE_BEG` to work:

### test.c

```c
#include "test.h"

VALUE rb_mTest = Qnil;
VALUE rb_cTest = Qnil;

VALUE super_initialize(VALUE self) {
  return self;
}

VALUE array_len(VALUE self, VALUE ary) {
  Check_Type(ary, T_ARRAY);
  return LONG2NUM(RARRAY_LEN(ary));       // this works
}

VALUE range_begin(VALUE self, VALUE rng) {
  if (rb_obj_is_kind_of(rng, rb_cRange)) {
    // return RANGE_BEG(rng);                          // doesn't work
    return rb_funcall(rng, rb_intern("begin"), 0);     // this works
  }
  return Qnil;
}

void Init_test(void) {
  rb_mTest = rb_define_module("RangeTest");
  rb_cTest = rb_define_class_under(rb_mTest, "Tester", rb_cObject);

  rb_define_method(rb_cTest, "initialize", super_initialize, 0);
  rb_define_method(rb_cTest, "array_len", array_len, 1);
  rb_define_method(rb_cTest, "begin_value", range_begin, 1);
}
```

### test.h

```c
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H 1

#include "ruby.h"

VALUE super_initialize(VALUE self);
void Init_test(void);
VALUE range_begin(VALUE self, VALUE rng);
VALUE array_len(VALUE self, VALUE ary);

#endif /* TEST_H */
```

When the commented line is made active, the compiler generates this error message:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'RANGE_BEG' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    return RANGE_BEG(rng);
           ^
1 error generated.
```

This sounds to me like I'm missing an `include`, but 1) no additional include is required for `RARRAY_LEN`; 2) including `range.h` didn't change anything; and 3) I've failed to find where `RANGE_BEG` is defined when I tried searching with `grep`.

As you can see, I have a work-around using `rb_funcall` but would like to know why one macro found in the Ruby source works while another doesn't. The extension docs I've looked at have also implied that the macro versions are more efficient than function call versions for data access, so using the macro would be preferable.

To sum up, I'm hoping anybody can tell me a suitable incantation to get the compiler to access `RANGE_BEG`. This is happening on MacOS 12.4 (Monterey) using `ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin21]` installed by HomeBrew, with `CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/include` and `LDFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason the `RANGE_XXX` macros are not included in the API headers. They are only defined and used in the [internal Ruby implementation itself](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/internal/range.h). It seems they wanted to keep these methods private, probably to ensure backwards and forward compatibility in case the internal implementation changes over time.

However, you get almost identical access through the API by using the provided method `rb_range_values`:

```
int rb_range_values(VALUE range, VALUE *begp, VALUE *endp, int *exclp);
```

You can peek at its implementation [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/33100797c48203528056489f30a350d1c8dbe188/range.c#L1490), where you can see it actually makes use of those internal macros.

To use it you simply have to define the returned variables and then call:

```
 VALUE beg;
 VALUE end;
 int excl;
 rb_range_values(range, &beg, &end, &excl);
```

Although this method does a little bit more than you need, it seeems likely it is still faster than a version using `funcall`, but you would need to benchmark to make sure.

Comment: This is exactly the info I was looking for - both why it fails, and how to do it right.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Follow up - Yes, this made a huge difference in my actual gem.  100M iterations went from 11.4 seconds down to 7.2 seconds.  Very cool!

Comment: The friendly ghost comes through yet again. I would like to welcome him and his fellow Finlanders to the club.